# Install Drush error on bluehost

Tags: drush, composer

I am following instructions at https://www.drupal.org/node/2366283 to install Drush at bluehost.com using PuTTY. I'm stuck at the install composer step. I tried the curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php command and got 500 Internal Server Error. Support at bluehost was useless.

I tried wget https://getcomposer.org/installer | php and got the following messages.

--2015-10-27 10:00:40--  https://getcomposer.org/installer
Resolving getcomposer.org... 87.98.253.108, 2001:41d0:a:7b19::1
Connecting to getcomposer.org|87.98.253.108|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 275841 (269K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: `installer'

100%[======================================>] 275,841      344K/s   in 0.8s

2015-10-27 10:00:42 (344 KB/s) - `installer' saved [275841/275841]

Content-type: text/html

I then went to the next step and typed mv composer.phar bin/composer.phar

I got the following.
mv: cannot stat `composer.phar': No such file or directory

What does this mean? How can I fix this?

Comment: I would imagine Blue host would not allow this, but you should probably check with them.

Comment: You've downloaded the file to "installer". So `sudo mv installer /usr/bin/composer; sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/composer`, assuming you have correct permissions

Comment: Thanks Clive. That solved the problem after I changed the command to mv installer bin/composer.